# from PIL import Image Error: Issue getting during Image

Tags: tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import PIL
from PIL import Image


class Ab:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("1530x790+0+0")
        self.root.title("Management System")


if __name__=="__main__":
    root=Tk()
    obj=Ab(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

> I am getting an Error while importing PIL. I am not understanding this
> error as I have already installed Pillow library.

---

I have removed tkinter but still observing this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'.
I have already installed Pillow but getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `from tkinter import PIL`. That should solve the problem.

You cannot import PIL from tkinter as PIL is a separate Python Imaging Library.
Once you have installed the Pillow library, you can directly use `from PIL import Image`. You need not add `PIL` to the namespace before using a function or object provided by PIL.